# What Happens When Django-Rest-Framework Receives a Request?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to understand how DRF works, specifically the GenericViewSet view.

What is the events sequence when a request is retrieved?
Which component receives the request? 
To where the request is passed? 
When does validation happen?

Context: All of my field-choices enums are lowercased, so I was trying to lowercase all values that arrive (from uncontrolled 3rd parties). Django's model validation fails before any of the exposed GenericViewSet methods are called. How can I process request data before model validation?

Can anyone shed some light on the topic?

Comment: I think you should use a debugger to find the problem, and it might take a long time :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest overriding the method for which you're trying to debug.

You could then plaec a breakpoint to explore the current scope. Builtin modules such as `pdb` are great for this! Here is an example using `rest_framework.generics.CreateAPIView`. Note that you can access the post data using `request.data` whilst in the trace.

```
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView
import pdb;
...
class ExampleCreateView(CreateAPIView):

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pdb.set_trace()
        return super(ExampleCreateView, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the method to debug is what I'm trying to find. I know I can do that, but request.data is received only after model validation happens. Where does it happen?

Comment: Model validation on serialization happens in the model serializer class within the `is_valid` method of `rest_framework.serializers.Serializer` (assuming you're using rest_framework serializers). As far as I understand, the request.data should be JSON and is only validated and serialised into instances of your models __after__ the super class `rest_framwork.generics.CreateAPIView.create` method is called. You say "request.data is received only after model validation happens" could you please explain what you mean by this?

Comment: Thanks for your response! What I mean is that an HTTP "Invalid request" response is already returned before `rest_framwork.generics.CreateAPIView.create` is called, so `is_valid` must be called somewhere else before that. I was trying to modify request.data to pass validation inside of create, but it useless due to what I've just explained.

Comment: It's more than likely that the HTTP "Invalid request" which you're receiving does not originate from the serializer `is_valid` method. I would suggest checking (or systematically disabling for your view) the permission, authentication, CORS or other third party middleware modules. Alternatively if you still believe the issue originates from the `is_valid` method and you wish to override any and all serialization, try using the rest_framework.views.APIView class rather than generics.